# File ended while scanning use of \frac

Tags: floats, equations, amsmath, amssymb

I keep receiving the error message

> File ended while scanning use of \frac ."

and have narrowed the error down to this equation, though I can't work out why.

```
\documentclass [12pt] {report}

\usepackage [doublespacing] {setspace}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage [top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=2cm] {geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}

\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{MN}{D}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{N^2}{D}\right)+ gD\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+\frac{\tau_{y}}{p}=0\\

\label{eq2}

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Additionally, if I remove all the unnecessary content, I can't replicate the results. All `\frac`s are properly structured in your code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that you mustn't have blank lines in an `equation` environment -- or *any* display-math environment, for that matter.

An additional concern: If you use Times Roman as the text font, you should probably also load a Times Roman math font. The `mathptmx` and `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` packages may be suitable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math fonts
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, left=4cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% For tighter spacing around \left/\right pairs of parentheses:
\usepackage{mleftright}  \mleftright 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{MN}{D}\right)
 +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{N^2}{D}\right)+ gD\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}
 +\frac{\tau_{y}}{p}=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\frac{\partial N}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{MN}{D}\right) + 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{N^2}{D}\right) + 
gD\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + 
\frac{\tau_{y}}{p}=0\\
```

You must remove the extra curly brace in the last summand.

Comment: Which curly brace are you referring to?  You've bolded 3 pairs, but they balance correctly.  And I count 12 unbolded pairs that also balance correctly.